# How to print a grouped_df grouped by two variables on two tables with dplyr in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to group by two variables, compute a mean for the groups, then print the result on  distinct tables.
Unlike the below where I get all my means in a single table, I would like one output table for x==1 and another one for x==2

````
data = tibble(x=factor(sample(1:2,10,rep=TRUE)),
              y=factor(sample(letters[1:2],10,rep=TRUE)),
              z=1:10)
data %>% group_by(x) %>% summarize(Mean_z=mean(z))

res = data %>% group_by(x,y) %>% summarize(Mean_z=mean(z))
print(res)

res %>% knitr::kable() %>% kableExtra::kable_styling()```
````

Comment: To @Gilles Guillot please can you review the answer and accept it if it answers your question or comment if not. Thanks

Comment: @MarkDavies many thanks and apologies for the delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want separate outputs for when x==1 and x==2. A simple way with `dplyr` would be to `filter`:

```
library(dplyr)
data = tibble(x=factor(sample(1:2,10,rep=TRUE)),
              y=factor(sample(letters[1:2],10,rep=TRUE)),
              z=1:10)

res = data %>% group_by(x,y) %>% summarize(Mean_z=mean(z))

x1= res%>%
  filter(x ==1)

x2= res%>%
  filter(x ==2)

x1 %>% knitr::kable() %>% kableExtra::kable_styling()
x2 %>% knitr::kable() %>% kableExtra::kable_styling()
```

I'm not sure why you have this line of code:

```
data %>% group_by(x) %>% summarize(Mean_z=mean(z))
```

It doesn't create a new object and so it's output won't be available to be used in subsequent lines of code. If you did use it, it would give you the means for z for each x value, without splitting into each y value.